# Dynamic content in javascript

Tags: javascript

This may be obvious to someone.  I am trying to place a textbox on the screen under a specific circumstance and I am using the following code:

```
document.getElementById('tbDetails').innerHTML = '<textarea name="taComments" style="height:40px;width:333px" class="f1 greytext" onblur="sb_textarea_onblur(this, \'Check Out Rhapsody Tours\'s Video:\')" onfocus="sb_textarea_onfocus(this, \'Check Out Rhapsody Tours\'s Video:\')">Check Out Rhapsody Tours's Video:</textarea>';
```

as you can see the text has a apostrophe "Check Out Rhapsody Tours's Video:" which is causing an error.  The text is created dynamically in classic asp so there is no way to tell which information will be displayed.

Other code that may help:

```
function sb_textarea_onfocus(txt,defaultText)
{
     if(txt&&txt.value == defaultText)
     {
         txt.value = '';
         txt.className = 'f1';
     }
}

function sb_textarea_onblur(txt,defaultText)
{
     if(txt&&txt.value == '')
     {
          txt.value = defaultText;
          txt.className = 'f1 greytext';
     }
}
```

I just need a way to correct the javascript to allow apostrophes...  Any idea..

Many thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You missed one apostrophe in

   > Check Out Rhapsody Tours's Video:
2. Inside a string you want to escape-escape -> `\\\'`  three backslashes and then apostrophe.

Comment: Many thanks for your help with this issue... this resolved it!

Answer (score 0):

Escape all the quotes and double quotes by putting a backslash in front of them:

```
text.replace(/'/g, "\\'").replace(/"/g, '\\"')
```

E.g.

```
"foo's bar is \"baz\"".replace(/'/g, "\\'").replace(/"/g, '\\"')
```

Yields

```
foo\'s bar is \"baz\"
```

Edit: Just realised this I assumed you were getting your content dynamically somehow. If you're just shoving a hard-coded string in there, then the answers above re: just escape the spare quote, will suffice.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('tbDetails').innerHTML = '<textarea name="taComments" style="height:40px;width:333px" class="f1 greytext" onblur="sb_textarea_onblur(this, \'Check Out Rhapsody Tours\'s Video:\')" onfocus="sb_textarea_onfocus(this, \'Check Out Rhapsody Tours\'s Video:\')">Check Out Rhapsody Tours\'s Video:</textarea>';
```

In this code you can see a backslash before the apostrophe which converts it to a part of the string. The problem was caused by this apostrophe because your `Check Out Rhapsody Tours'` makes the browser think the string is ended unless you replace ' with \'.